# python dict comprehension generating list value

Tags: python, dictionary-comprehension

After WAAY too much time I've reduced a much bigger issue down to this simplified example.

I have a list and a dict; the dict has repeated values,

```
addresses = ['everywhere', 'there', 'here']
names_addr = {'tom': 'here', 'candide': 'here', 'fred': 'here', \
              'scott': 'there', 'phillipa': 'there', 'harry': 'there', \
              'melissa': 'everywhere', 'rich': 'everywhere', 'nick': 'everywhere'}
```

I want to generate a dictionary with keys consisting of the items in addresses opposite values which are names_addr.keys with the corresponding values.

```
objective = {'here': ['tom', 'candide', 'fred'], \
             'there': ['scott', 'phillipa', 'harry' ], \
             'everywhere': ['melissa', 'rich', 'nick']}

# my naif dict comprehension overwrites to generate
{addr:name for name,addr in names_addr.items() if addr in addresses}
# {'here': 'fred', 'there': 'harry', 'everywhere': 'nick'}
```

How can I accumulate the names list?
Alternative solutions are welcome!

Comment: Can you make a list for a single name?  If so, you can apply that to every name in `addresses`.

Comment: Just add your `if addr in addresses` from the code given in the link and you're done

Comment: If you really want a dict-comp, you can use the very inefficient and not recommended: `{add: [name for name, val in names_addr.items() if val == add] for add in addresses}`

Answer (score 0):

I think you could probably do something like this:

```py
objective = {}

# Initialize the dict with empty list values
for addr in addresses:
    objective["addr"] = []

# Append the names to the generated list
for k,v in names_addr.items()
    if k not in objective[v]:
        objective[v].append[k]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `collections.defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

addresses = ['everywhere', 'there', 'here']
names_addr = {'tom': 'here', 'candide': 'here', 'fred': 'here', \
              'scott': 'there', 'phillipa': 'there', 'harry': 'there', \
              'melissa': 'everywhere', 'rich': 'everywhere', 'nick': 'everywhere'}

d = defaultdict(list)              
for k, v in names_addr.items():
    d[v].append(k)

print(d)
# defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'here': ['tom', 'candide', 'fred'], 'there': ['scott', 'phillipa', 'harry'], 'everywhere': ['melissa', 'rich', 'nick']})
```